# Find the name of subdirectories and process files in each

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-findutils

Let's say `/tmp` has subdirectories `/test1`, `/test2`, `/test3` and so on,
and each has multiple files inside.

I have to run a `while` loop or `for` loop to find the name of the directories (in this case `/test1`, `/test2`, ...)
and run a command that processes all the files inside of each directory.

So, for example,
I have to get the directory names under `/tmp` which will be `test1`, `test2`, ...
For each subdirectory, I have to process the files inside of it.

How can I do this?

---

Clarification:

This is the command that I want to run:

```
find /PROD/140725_D0/ -name "*.json" -exec /tmp/test.py {} \;
```

where `140725_D0` is an example of *one* subdirectory to process - there are multiples, with different names.

So, by using a `for` or `while` loop, I want to find all subdirectories and run a command on the files in each.

The `for` or `while` loop should iteratively replace the hard-coded name `140725_D0` in the find command above.

Comment: I've cleaned up your question; if you look a the question's source now, you should be able to infer how code is formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do with a *single* `find` command with an *embedded shell command*:

```
find /PROD -type d -execdir sh -c 'for f in *.json; do /tmp/test.py "$f"; done' \;
```

<sup>Note: `-execdir` is not POSIX-compliant, but the BSD (OSX) and GNU (Linux) versions of `find` support it; see below for a POSIX alternative.</sup>

- The approach is to let `find` match *directories*, and then, in each matched directory, *execute a shell with a file-processing loop* (`sh -c '<shellCmd>'`).
- If not all subdirectories are guaranteed to have `*.json` files, change the shell command to `for f in *.json; do [ -f "$f" ] && /tmp/test.py "$f"; done`

Update: Two more considerations; tip of the hat to [kenorb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28861001/45375):

- By default, `find` processes the *entire subtree* of the input directory. To limit matching to *immediate* subdirectories, use `-maxdepth 1`<sup>[1]</sup>:

  ```
  find /PROD -maxdepth 1 -type d ...
  ```
- As stated, `-execdir` - which runs the command passed to it in the directory currently being processed - is not POSIX compliant; you can work around this by using `-exec` instead and by including a `cd` command with the directory path at hand (`{}`) in the *shell* command:

  ```
  find /PROD -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" && for f in *.json; do /tmp/test.py "$f"; done' \;
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, you can place the `-maxdepth` option *anywhere after the input file paths* on the `find` command line - as an *option*, it is not positional. However, GNU `find` will issue a warning unless you place it *before* *tests* (such as `-type`) *and* *actions* (such as `-exec`).</sup>

Comment: Where can I add maxdepth? does it come before -exec or after?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following usage of `find`:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" && echo Do some stuff for {}, files are: $(ls *.*)' ';'
```

Use `-maxdepth` if you'd like to limit your directory levels.

Comment: Kudos for `-maxdepth` and the POSIX-compliant `-execdir` alternative (`-exec` + `cd "{}"`  inside shell command).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using bash's subshell feature like so

```
for i in /tmp/test*; do
  # don't do anything if there's no /test directory in /tmp
  [ "$i" != "/tmp/test*" ] || continue

  for j in $i/*.json; do
    # don't do anything if there's nothing to run
    [ "$j" != "$i/*.json" ] || continue

    (cd $i && ./file_to_run)
  done
done
```

When you wrap a command in `(` and `)` it starts a subshell to run the command.  A subshell is exactly like starting another instance of bash except it's slightly more optimal.

Comment: I meant to say that.. lets say you don't know if tmp contains /test*.. you need to check the directory to see what is in there and run each directories. also you don't know what files are in there.. lets say each sub-directories contains few json files.. you need to run all json

Comment: So i think it might be better to use while loop so that I can run the files if there are any sub directories.. and if there are, find that name and run that sub directories

Comment: ok sorry for making confusion..  this is the command that I want to run "find /PROD/140725_D0/ -name "*.json" -exec /tmp/test.py {} \;" and 140725_D0 is one of the sub-directory and there are multiples of that (each name of the directories are different)..  so by doing for or while loop i want to find all that directories and run that command.. for or while loop should replace that directory name on the find command

Comment: Two suggestions: double-quote `$i` in `cd $i`; instead of repeating the glob to test if anything matched, use `[ -e "$i ] || continue`, for instance (or, more bash-like, `[[ -e $i ]] || continue`. Better yet, use `[[ -d $i ]]` and `[[ -f $j ]]` to limit matches to the type of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply ask the shell to expand the directories/files you need, e.g. using command `xargs`:

```
echo /PROD/*/*.json | xargs -n 1 /tmp/test.py
```

or even using your original `find` command:

```
find /PROD/* -name "*.json" -exec /tmp/test.py {} \;
```

Both command will process all JSON files contained into any subdirectory of `/PROD`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to change slightly the Python code inside your script in order to accept and process multiple files.
For example, if your script contains something like:

```
def process(fname):
    print 'Processing file', fname

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    process(sys.argv[1])
```

you could replace the last line with:

```
    for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
        process(fname)
```

After this simple modification, you can call your script this way:

```
/tmp/test.py /PROD/*/*.json
```

and have it process all the desired JSON files.